# Reading bytes from network socket in Python

Tags: python, sockets, byte

I want to write a Python program that gets data from a network socket and then scans the data looking for particular sequences of data.

The 'getting from the network' bit works fine, and I can dump the retrieved data to a file with no problem, but trying to get Python to actually scan the data one byte at a time is just not working.

Whenever I put code in to try and work things in the 'for byte' loop, I don't get anything much to happen.

When I run the program below, the size of byte.out is usually twice the size of buf.out, which I think is a major symptom pointing to what has gone wrong. If the inner loop were really dealing with the data byte by byte, I would expect both output files to be the same size.

My feeling is that there is something wrong with "for byte in chr(buf):" but I really don't know what to put here.

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)

fh1 = open("buf.out", 'wb')
fh2 = open("byte.out", 'wb')

s.connect(("obscured.url", 9999))
s.send('GET /xx HTTP/1.1\nHost obscured.url:9999\n\n')

for i in range(10):
    buf = s.recv(1024)

    for byte in chr(buf):
        print >>fh2, byte

    print >>fh1, buf
s.close
```

Comment: Just a quick hunch: try `str(buf)` instead of `chr(buf)`?

Comment: Or just `for byte in buf`?  And is the doubling in size because you're printing a newline for every byte? - Did you want `print >>fh2, byte,`?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you do not use `urllib` or `urllib2`?

Comment: @akaIDIOT: Didn't seem make any difference.

Comment: @RichieHindle: I started with just 'for byte in buf' and when that didn't seem to work I started googling, and trying out things suggested on pages I found.  You are quite correct that the doubling was being caused by newlines. I should have spotted that when I saw all the 0a in od -x, but it was late and I was tired, and this red herring threw me off the trail. I tried putting the , on the end and now it is doubling up with spaces instead.

Comment: @RichieHindle: Having been reassured that 'for byte in buf' is indeed correct, I have played around with other things and discovered that what I should have been doing was put ord() around my byte before comparing it to a number: eg if ord(byte) == 255. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @glglgl: Mainly for self-education. I like to write the first one by hand to ensure I properly understand what's going on 'under the hood' before I hand off to some library. I guess this is something that was emphasized during my uni days and the habit sort of stuck.

Comment: RicheHindle probably gave me the most useful information, but did not actually submit an answer. Hence I will have to accept the answer from Janne karila. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @KevinGolding: You can prevent the "doubling up with spaces" by using `fh2.write(byte)` rather than `print`.  `print` is intended for human-readable output, hence the automatic addition of newlines, spaces, etc.

Comment: @RichieHindle: Yes, .write(byte) stopped the doubling up from happening. Thanks for yet another useful tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chr(buf)` should give a TypeError. Use

```
for byte in buf:
```